# Azure Application Insights With SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, monitoring

I have set up Application Insights in Azure and monitoring some SharePoint Online sites.  The monitoring only seems to be available for client side and it works fine.  The code is embedded in the master page.

How can I configure the server charts as in the below screenshot in the blade in Azure so that it captures response times from server side for SharePoint Online?

i.e. server response time, server requests and failed requests.

These don't seem to present any data.

[image: Azure Blade]

Comment: As you won't be able to add server side code to Office 365, you will not be able to do this unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Azure insights doesn't provide any SharePoint Online based server response time and requests because you dont have the access to configure those settings in the infrastructure that SharePoint online is running at.

if your SharePoint instance is running at on-premises server environment or virtual machines where you have admin access then you should be able to track those parameters as well.